# Negative loop gain?

Tags: amplifier, audio, bjt, negative-feedback, loop-gain

I was dimensioning the CE capacitor. To do that I was looking at some formulas seen in class. The formula (freq_C=1/(2*pi*Req*C)) involves the knowledge of the loop gain (open loop gain*beta). It appears to be negative in my schematic. What does it mean? Is something wrong? In other exercises I've got a positive number: I though positive numbers were to be expected. 
This is the audio amplifier circuit I'm working on:
[image]

-- update --

@Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 I have upgraded the circuit but I haven't applied the 3:1 resistors value ratio in the Vbe multiplier since the quiescent current on the output resistors was several hundreds mA... The circuit is behaving better now though. Do you think that something is wrong? 
[image]

The fact that I have good phase margin (+90.8deg) and good gain margin (-37.8dB) (do you agree?) isn't enough to assure me stability? It looks like I still need miller compensation capacitor since I've got peaking. Why do i have peaking though?
[image]

Comment: That -6 degree is reasonably close to zero degrees. If it were closer to 180 or to -180 degrees, then I'd call it an "inverting amplifier" instead of the current "non-inverting". Or are you thinking the minus sign of -5 dB magnitude is involved?

Comment: Lucky, When I design something like this, I sit down and make choices and then make calculations. Then I simulate and usually find out that I was right. But sometimes I also learn something new. But I don't see any calculations here or even any thought processes behind them. Could you share your thinking about the above schematic? (One of the things in the schematic that really shocks me is your use of RF1 and RF2. It just stands out like a sore thumb as "not right.")

Comment: @jonk This design has massive open loop gain and due to lack of CC  biasing is easily saturated. Closed loop gain is extreme with almost 40dB out of 90 dB but has excessive input bias current and offset sensitivity. My suggestions will patch it but rather than a bandaid it needs better DC stability.. negative gain comes from saturation.

Comment: @TonyStewart The RF1 and RF2 resistors are "resistors to nowhere." That supposed feedback isn't happening in the OP's circuit. He's broken the connection that could make it work (and it lacks other elements, but that's a separate issue.) I stopped bothering to look further the moment I saw that.

Comment: @jonk That was his annotation  to show how open loop gain was tested and failed. I explained why and how to fix it. He wanted to do that to see what RC breakpoint was needed to give adequate gain margin. But of course, it could have been done other ways with a closed cloop.

Comment: Perhaps you can steer him in the right direction with a more stable DC bias method.

Comment: @TonyStewart Not tonight. But perhaps. It's nice of you to imagine I might be able to help. It's not deserved. But there is a familiar topology here. R9 annoys me a lot. I'd almost certainly go with a current mirror there instead. But I can work with it. The NFB is horrible, even with your comments saying that it was how he tested things. It's just wrong in several ways. And I get tired thinking about other corrections. But the skeleton is there, kind of. Tomorrow I'll see if I feel I can add any value.

Comment: @lucky did you try my suggestions yet?

Comment: @jonk Why are you so aggressive? RF1 and RF2 are attached to the the output thanks to "vo" label. After I've seen peaking in my circuit with feedback I decided to choose a capacitor for Q8. To choose its size I grounged the negative input detaching the feedback in order to get the loop gain using an ac analysis. I was following this path: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/negative-feedback-part-5-gain-margin-and-phase-margin/ After that I can find the frequency of the pole of the added capacitor. After that I can find the size of the capacitor with the formula I mentioned.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 in less than an hour I'll give it a try: right now I'm away from my notebook, thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @Lucky-Luka Tony pointed out to me that I misunderstood. That happens. You'll need a zero in the feedback loop, too. Just FYI.

Comment: How can I add a zero in the feedback loop? Is it a capacitor? How can I dimension it?

Comment: You can’t do anything about C until you learn to bias Vout near 0 . where did you get this design from?

Comment: Electronic college course and some help from forums... I have more or less understood it, it's not like I've just copied it...

Comment: Add an LC filter between net loop-gain and the base of Q9 to allow DC feedback but block all practical signal frequencies. Like a 1GigH inductor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is saturated open loop due to offset between sensitivity to R5, R9 values and hFE assumptions. I can tell by your choice of R9 = 595 Ohms and Vout = 14.3V

- Increase R5 to say 4k7  until you get in the linear output range and test Aol with 1uVpp input.  You don't have to null it.
- Also your 4 Vbe output bias circuit needs to be more than 3:1 R ratio to make 3+1=4.  Vbe=0.6V @ 1mA and 0.65V @ 10mA so the crossover output bias should be not 1.4 AMPS.
- let R3/R4 >=3:1 consider R3/R4 = 3.0.

  - With 0.6V across R4 you expect  3x this amount across R3.
- you might expect Aol > 90dB

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. - What does  "Aol" mean? - Can you please explain this statement  "Also your 4 Vbe output bias circuit needs to be more than 3:1 R ratio to make 3+1=4. Vbe=0.6V @ 1mA and 0.65V @ 10mA so the crossover output bias should be not 1.4 AMPS." a little more?

Comment: Which quiescent current on Q1 and Q2 you had in mind when you wrote" Also your 4 Vbe output bias circuit needs to be more than 3:1 R ratio to make 3+1=4. Vbe=0.6V @ 1mA and 0.65V @ 10mA so the crossover output bias should be not 1.4 AMPS."?

Comment: Using the 3:1 ratio I get 500mA and more quiescent current flowing in R1. It looks like 720ohm and 1500ohm works just fine giving Iqc=45mA or 680ohm and 1130ohm giving Iqc=18mA on R1. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Lucky-Luka No . To prevent crossover distortion, you need to match the voltage of 2 Darlingtons or  4 times Vbe .  Which means you need 3x VBE across R3. roughly. Since R4 =Vbe, then R3/R4=3. This is called a diode voltage amplifier

Comment: Aol is often used to define open loop gain.

Comment: I have updated the question with circuit upgrade. Can you have a look at it please?

Comment: better but not perfect.  Examine this to understand diode voltage multiplier  http://tinyurl.com/ygxpzzs4  use in Class AB bias must be thermally matched to driver heatsink  vshttp://tinyurl.com/yjoant8s

Comment: Why did you make us assume what is Vcc,Vee =16V when this controls bias current and output offset. This is a problem solved in all Op Amps and power amps using CC sources  and thermal matched  class AB voltage bias using above.  . The lower Resistor is chosen to determine output voltage, when it should be done with R Ratios. which are easier to control in IC's . As for C gain near 100 with 10MHz BW is obviously too much BW for stable operation which is another reason why RC snubbers are used on speaker output . But you can improve by adding C with 1st order response (LPF)  . good luck